# What is the alternative of date_trunc in mysql?

Tags: mysql

As date_trunc function is not in mysql so what can we use in this code:

```
Select date_trunc(‘week’, b.occured_at), 
count(distinct b.user_id) as users_active
from events b
where b.event_type = ‘engagement’
and b.event_type = ‘login’
group by 1
order by 1;
```

and in

```
select date_trunc('day', created_at) as days,
count(*) as users, 
count( case 
           when activated_at is not null then u.user_id 
           else null 
           end ) as active_users
from users u
where created_at >='2013-05-01' and created_at <= '2013-05-31' 
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: What exactly is `date_trunc()` and what exactly is it supposed to do?

Comment: extract some date terms from the given time @user207421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so since you're talking about `Day` & `Week` precisions, the time aspect of it becomes irrelevant. So probable solution that comes to my mind is that you use `DATE_FORMAT` to get only the date part dynamically and keep the time part of it static. Let me show you how you can do the same with an example below:

##### Database schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE rental
(
    rent_id INT NOT NULL,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    checkin_date TIMESTAMP,
    employee_id INT,
    checkout_date TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO rental (rent_id,customer_id,checkin_date,employee_id,checkout_date)
VALUES
(1,5382,'2021-09-10 22:10:34',1,'2021-09-18 10:10:48'),
(2,5383,'2019-01-25 19:06:52',1,'2019-01-26 07:06:52'),
(3,5384,'2019-01-26 16:06:34',2,'2019-01-27 04:06:33');
```

**So now, I want to query the `checkout_date` with day & week precision.**

##### Solution

```sql
SELECT 
rent_id,
WEEKDAY(checkout_date) as weekday,
DATE_FORMAT(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z') as day_precision, 
DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(checkout_date, WEEKDAY(checkout_date)), '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z') as week_precision
FROM rental;
```

##### Output

| rent_id | weekday | day_precision | week_precision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-09-18T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-09-13T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2 | 5 | 2019-01-26T00:00:00.000Z | 2019-01-21T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3 | 6 | 2019-01-27T00:00:00.000Z | 2019-01-21T00:00:00.000Z |

##### Explaination

- `DATE_FORMAT(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z') as day_precision`

> Here we are just population the date part of it from the db and telling `MySQL` to keep the rest of time part of it static since day precision doesn't really care about the time.

- `DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(checkout_date, WEEKDAY(checkout_date)), '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z') as week_precision`

> Here we are just finding out how far the current day is from the start of the week and then subtracting those many number of days from the date, to arrive at the date that points to the start of the week. This date is then formatted to out advantage.

##### Answer to your problem

```sql
-- 1st Query
Select DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(b.occured_at, WEEKDAY(b.occured_at)), '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z') as week_precision,
count(distinct b.user_id) as users_active
from events b
where b.event_type = ‘engagement’
and b.event_type = ‘login’
group by 1
order by 1;

-- 2nd Query
select DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z') as day_precision,
count(*) as users, 
count( case 
           when activated_at is not null then u.user_id 
           else null 
           end ) as active_users
from users u
where created_at >='2013-05-01' and created_at <= '2013-05-31' 
group by 1
order by 1;
```

##### DbFiddle Demo

Nevertheless, you can also play around & compare the results of `MySQL` & `PostGreSQL` for yourself [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Pz9GQ1aZ2jrDfr1gSmyzU/0). I've kept both the queries, so that you can switch the db servers in the top left corner to check and compare the results.

Comment: THAnks A ton :) THanks for your precious time.

Comment: Upvote the answer if you can, so that it can boost me to give more answers to the community in future.